# how can I center amp-img vertically?

Tags: html, css, amp-html

I'm trying to center an [`<amp-img>`](https://amp.dev/documentation/components/amp-img/?format=websites) in a div vertically.

```
<div class="outer" style="height: 100vh">
  <amp-img class="inner" layout="responsive"></amp-img>
</div>
```

So far I've tried these ways, but they don't work:

#### First

```
.outer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center; 
}
```

In this case, the image disappears.

#### Second

```
.outer {
  line-height: 100vh
}

.inner {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: center;
}
```

Also the image's size goes to `0 x 0` and the image disppears.

#### And so on

Other ways also make the image disppear or don't work as expected.

Is there a way to center `<amp-img>` vertically by any chance?

Comment: remove layout="responsive" and specify the height and width like this    <amp-img class="inner" height="200" width="200" src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" alt="Welcome" ></amp-img>

Comment: @AmareshSM I thought `layout` is required. However as you said, that is not required, right?

Comment: flex box itself makes flexible responsive layout structure so no need of layout="responsive". I think layout attribute also used make the same.check this link:https://amp.dev/documentation/guides-and-tutorials/develop/style_and_layout/control_layout/?referrer=ampproject.org

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first example was very close to solution:

See example:

```css
 .inner{
    flex-basis: 0;
    -ms-flex-preferred-size: 0;
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    -ms-flex-positive: 1;
    flex-grow: 1;
  }
  .outer {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100vh
  }
```

```html
<div class="outer">
    <amp-img class="inner" layout="responsive">your image</amp-img>
</div>
```